# How do I stop score going up by more than one after collision?

Tags: ios, swift, collision

Creating a angry birds type project and I have the ball flying at the target and after collision the target disappears but the score goes up continuously while the ball is in the frame of the target even after its removed from subview.

```
  let enemy1 = UIImageView(image: nil)
        enemy1.image = UIImage(named: "enemy2.png")
        enemy1.frame = CGRect(x: w*0.85, y: h*0.035, width: w*0.12, height: h*0.22)
        self.view.addSubview(enemy1)



 collisionBehaviour.action = {
        for boulderView in self.bouldersArray{
            if boulderView.frame.intersects(enemy1.frame){
                enemy1.removeFromSuperview()
                self.scoreCount += 1
                self.scoreCountLabel.text = "Score: \(self.scoreCount)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach could be to check if the enemy1 view is still there:

```
collisionBehaviour.action = {
                if enemy1.superview != nil {
                    //your code
                    for boulderView in self.bouldersArray {
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: I did this and when the ball goes through the score stays at zero so In guessing the view is there  if enemy1.superview != nil{
                            self.scoreCount += 1
                            self.scoreCountLabel.text = "Score: \(self.scoreCount)"
                    }